# SQL: How do I find duplicate rows in a table which are after the first occurring record?

Tags: sql, database, relational-database

Would love some feedback on how I'd retrieve duplicate rows from a table which occurred only after the originating record.

So for example, the id is unique, but the second column, a text field, was duplicated.  Here's what a record might look like:

```
ID: 1    text column: 'email1'
ID: 2    text column: 'email1'
ID: 3    text column: 'email2'
ID: 4    text column: 'email2'
```

So for this data set, I would need to retrive ID 2 and 4

Comment: Hi. There is no "after" unless you give a sort order. (Maybe you mean, per a certain ordering of ID?) Tables are unordered, result sets [sic] are. You are also not clear, use enough words, sentences and descriptions to say what you mean, and what your example is an example *of*. Enough that someone could leave with your question & know exactly what you want. As if we don't know what you're talking about--because we don't. That includes "retrieve duplicate rows".

Answer (score 2):

Do a self join. If you find another record with lower id and same email, then you are a duplicated record.

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.id
FROM yourTable t1
JOIN yourTable t2
  ON t1.id > t2.id
 AND t1.email = t2.email
```

Data:

```
ID: 1    text column: 'email1'
ID: 2    text column: 'email1'
ID: 3    text column: 'email2'
ID: 4    text column: 'email2'
ID: 5    text column: 'email1'
```

In this case `ID: {1,2,5}` are `email1`:

```
ID: 5 > {1,2} 
ID: 2 > {1}
```

So `ID: 5` will appear twice because the `JOIN` condition `ON t1.id > t2.id` that is why `DISTINCT t1.id` is required so `ID: 5` appear only one time as duplicated

Answer (score -1):

```
<strike>SELECT *
FROM myTable
WHERE myColumn IN 
(SELECT DISTINCT myColumn FROM myTable) 
AND id != (SELECT MIN(id) FROM myTable WHERE mycolumn = myTable.myColumn)</strike>
```

My previous answer was wrong so I felt I should correct it. Taking into account the comment below, I should also explain: get the complete list of all the IDs of the original posts (MIN(id) for each name) and then select from your database all the records that do not have IDs in that list.

```
SELECT id
FROM myTable
WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT MIN(id) FROM myTable 
GROUP BY name);
```

As answered above, you could also do a Join

Comment: Please describe your answer shortly instead of just posting the code.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE tbl1
JOIN (SELECT MIN(ID) as minID, TextField 
      FROM TABLE 
      GROUP BY TextField) tbl2 
  on tbl2.textField = tbl1.textfield
WHERE tbl1.ID > tbl2.minID
```

Comment: You make an effort to update my answer. But you dont need edit for that, just leave a comment next time. I add more content to explain why `DISTINCT` is required hope make things clear now.

Comment: Yea I guess that way of doing it works here, but I would typically avoid using distinct for this type of operation.

Comment: As you said it is finding id 5 twice, so the bigger the data gets on this, the more you are going to be comparing records needlessly. It is a bad way to do this imo... if an email had 5000 records, then you will see how many extra decisions this query has to make.

Answer (score -1):

```
create table ForExample (ID int, Value nvarchar(3))

insert into ForExample select 1, 'one'
insert into ForExample select 2, 'one'
insert into ForExample select 3, 'two'
insert into ForExample select 4, 'two'
insert into ForExample select 5, 'one'

select t1.id 
from ForExample t1
join
(
    select min(id) minId, Value
    from ForExample 
    group by Value
) t2 
    on t1.ID != t2.minId 
    and t1.Value = t2.Value
```

Answer (score -1):

Thanks everyone for jumping in.  Here's another solution I was given from another developer which produces a set of the minimum ID's and makes them a set for NOT IN.

The sql uses a table with id and email as column names:

```
SELECT ID, EMAIL
FROM EMAIL
WHERE ID NOT IN (
      SELECT MIN_ID FROM (
            SELECT EMAIL, MIN(ID) AS MIN_ID FROM EMAIL GROUP BY EMAIL
      ) min_ids
)
```

Comment: You can simplify to `ID NOT IN (
      SELECT MIN(ID) AS MIN_ID FROM EMAIL GROUP BY EMAIL
      )`

Comment: Thanks Juan (and everyone else), both options work and continue to work as more records are added and altered in my testing